# JavaScript regex to find all Mustache partials

Tags: javascript, regex, mustache

I wanna find all partial views in a Mustache file.
The syntax for the partial views are defined as {{>somepartial}}.

For example:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>{{>name}}</li>
  </ul>
  <div>{{>footer}}</div>
</div>
```

There might be variations with spaces, like: `{{> partial}}`, `{{> partial }}`, etc.

Anyone know how a regex for this might be like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following `regex`:

```
str.match(/\{\{>\s*\w+\s*\}\}/g)
```

**Explanation**

1. `\{`: Matches `{` literal, need to escape
2. `\w+`: Matches any alphanumeric character one or more time
3. `\}`: Matches `}` literal, need to escape
4. `g`: Global matches
5. `\s*`: Matches any number of spaces

[**RegEx101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/fH1jE5/2)

Comment: @Hacketo I've updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Use `\s*` to match zero or more white spaces.

```
str.match(/\{\{\s*>\s*[\S\s]*?\}\}/g)
```

or

```
str.match(/\{\{\s*>\s*\w+\s*\}\}/g)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dO0mM8/6)